# swift RSS feed adding multiple cell content items

Tags: swift, rss, cells

Im am using a rss feed swift script by Ravi Shankar and trying to modify the code so it shows the rss description as well as just the title in the text cell and struggling to find why it won't show up.

Here is my swift file.

```
 //
//  BRTableViewController.swift
//  BlogReader
//
//  Created by Ravi Shankar on 31/07/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Ravi Shankar. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class BRTableViewController: UITableViewController, NSXMLParserDelegate {

var parser: NSXMLParser = NSXMLParser()
var blogPosts: [BlogPost] = []
var postTitle: String = String()
var postLink: String = String()
var postDescription: String = String()
var eName: String = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.adomain.co.uk/blog/feed")!
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: url)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
}

// MARK: - NSXMLParserDelegate methods

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    eName = elementName
    if elementName == "item" {
        postTitle = String()
        postLink = String()
        postDescription = String()
    }
}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String?) {
    let data = string!.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())
    if (!data.isEmpty) {
        if eName == "title" {
            postTitle += data
        } else if eName == "link" {
            postLink += data
        }
    } else if eName == "description" {
        postDescription += data
    }

}

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {
    if elementName == "item" {
        let blogPost: BlogPost = BlogPost()
        blogPost.postTitle = postTitle
        blogPost.postLink = postLink
        blogPost.postDescription = postDescription
        blogPosts.append(blogPost)
    }
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 3
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return blogPosts.count
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = blogPost.postTitle
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = blogPost.postDescription
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
    return cell
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
     return 150.0
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)  {
    if segue.identifier == "viewpost" {
        let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()?.row
        let blogPost: BlogPost = blogPosts[selectedRow!]
        let viewController = segue.destinationViewController as! PostViewController
        viewController.postLink = blogPost.postLink
    }
}
}
```

I am presuming i am missing some code relating to 
cell.detailTextLabel?.text =

Comment: Does this url work? - "http://www.adomain.co.uk/blog/feed". I am seeing page not found error.

Comment: No that is just a dummy domain as I didn't won't to post the real url. It is a standard Wordpress site so <description> is part of the rss item

Comment: Ok so I've worked out that the issue is you can't have two items in a cell label without creating an array...But I don't know how to alter the above code to display an array of items in the cell... Ie.  (Post title, description, pubdate) I've looked at other tutorials but can't work it out

Comment: You can create a custom tableviewcell to display these contents.

Comment: How would you do this modifying the existing code?